# translation based on selected app using getX package flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, translation, flutter-getx

I'm using GetX package and I have 3 apps inside one so total of 4,  i want to translate to make each app have its own translation file, currently im doing just one file for the whole app:
here's my main:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:iamonline/shared/localStrings.dart';
import 'package:iamonline/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:iamonline/proemr/screens/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(persistenceEnabled: true);
  await dotenv.load();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String languageCode = prefs.getString('languageCode') ?? 'en';
  String countryCode = prefs.getString('countryCode') ?? 'US';
  Locale locale = Locale(languageCode, countryCode);
  tz.initializeTimeZones();

  runApp(MyApp(locale: locale));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Locale locale;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.locale}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Brightness brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
    final bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;

    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      translations: LocalStrings(),
      locale: widget.locale,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''), // English
        const Locale('fr', ''), // French
        const Locale('hi', ''),
        const Locale('ar', ''),
        const Locale('es', ''),
        const Locale('de', ''),
        const Locale('it', ''),
        const Locale('ru', ''),
        const Locale('ja', ''),
        const Locale('pa', ''),
        const Locale('ta', ''),
        const Locale('gu', ''),
      ],
      theme: isDarkMode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
      home: Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
          },
          child: SplashScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here's where i navigate to that specific app from app1:

```
if (_showCards) // Only show the cards if _showCards is true
              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                width: 300.0,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: _pageController,
                  itemCount: enabledImages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        switch (enabledImages[index]) {
                          case 'assets/app2.jpg':
                          
                            Get.to(
                                () => app2(
                                      userInfo: widget.userInfo,
                                    ),
                                transition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade);
                            break;
                          case 'assets/app3.png':
                            Get.to(
                                () => app3(
                                      userInfo: widget.userInfo,
                                    ),
                                transition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade);
                            break;
                          case 'assets/app4.jpg':
                            Get.to(
                                () => app4(
                                      userInfo: widget.userInfo,
                                    ),
                                transition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade);
                            break;
                        }
                      },
```

here are my translation files i've created:
for localStrings.dart (what im currently using for the whole app):

```
class LocalStrings extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        //english language
        'en_US': {
    'Welcome, ': 'Welcome, ',
    }
     };
}
```

here's app2 example of translation file:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AppTwoLocalStrings extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
      
        'en_US': {
          'Welcome, ': 'Welcome to app2, ',
          "What would you like to do today?":
              "What would you like to do today for app2?"
        }
      };
}
```

I want when i navigate to for example to app2 splash and so on i get the translation based on the specific file.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've watched the video and found it informative. do you have any other recommendations for better translation packages?